# ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions' python

Tags: python, pandas

I have this error and I can't fix it.

**Error:**
`ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'functions'`

My code:

```
from functions import *
display_factorial_planes(X_reduced, 2, pca, [(0,1)], illustrative_var = clusters, alpha = 0.8)
plt.scatter(centres_reduced[:, 0], centres_reduced[:, 1],
        marker='x', s=169, linewidths=3,
        color='k', zorder=10)
```

Can you please help me to fix this issue ?

Comment: why would you expect it to have access to `functions`? is it a module you wrote, something you installed?

Comment: Without any information on `functions` as stated above, I can only recommend you to go through the modules documentations : https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/modules.html

Comment: There should be a file, functions.py, keep it in the same folder.